# Suggested method for extracting a standalone C library from an existing R package?

Tags: design, testing, c, refactoring, r

My group has been developing an R package to simulate plant growth (see [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ebimodeling/biocro)). The R package uses `.Call` to interface with C.

We have decided that it would be worthwhile to create a standalone C library. The two key reasons are 1) to use familiar C debugging tools and 2) a large portion of the developer / user community is familiar with compiled languages (mostly models in the class are written in C or Fortran). However, the R package is accessible to many outside this community, so we want to maintain its functionality.

I have reviewed some related questions, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/12328156/199217, that discuss R packages with C library dependencies, but have not found one that deals specifically with decoupling an existing R package.

#### A proposed approach

(what we have come up with so far ... a strawman)

1. Write tests for existing functionality
2. keep the C library inside the `src/` folder
3. Place R-specific C code (e.g. `SEXP`, loading R libraries, etc) into 'R wrapper' files prepended with `R_*`
4. create separate functions for reading configuration files in C
5. create a 'main' C function to replace functionality in R
6. write a makefile for the C library that ignores R wrapper files
7. Once the C library works independently and equivalently to the R package, we could consider moving the C functions to a separate repository, that would be a dependency for the R package

#### Questions:

1. Is this effort misguided?
2. Are we overlooking any potential pitfalls?
3. Is there a better way to develop both the R and C libraries in parallel?
4. Are there any examples of C libraries that have been decoupled from R packages?
5. How might we write tests to compare equivalent functions in R and C?

Comment: I don't know R internals, but generally speaking about embedding a library in some interpreter you should care a lot about memory management (i.e. garbage collection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, this is a fine idea and many packages do this. You might look at [`RSQLite`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/index.html) for inspiration -- they package up [`sqlite`](http://www.sqlite.org/) and just include some wrapper functions. Similar for [`rhdf5`](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/rhdf5.html) and [`hdf5`](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/)

Regarding your points:

> Write tests for existing functionality

Always a good idea!

> Keep the C library inside the `src/` folder

Yes -- or you could consider `inst/include` if you ever went the 'header-only' route, a la [`Rcpp`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html)

> Place R-specific C code (e.g. `SEXP`, loading R libraries, etc) into 'R wrapper' files prepended with `R_*`

Seems sensible enough.

> Create separate functions for reading configuration files in C

Not exactly sure what you mean here.

> Create a 'main' C function to replace functionality in R

This seems odd to me. Why do you need a `main` -- aren't you just developing a library of callable functions? Let R be your `main` :)

> Write a makefile for the C library that ignores R wrapper files

Yes, you will probably need a more involved `Makefile` to handle this -- I again suggest looking at the source code for RSQLite, and also [R-exts](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) may be helpful.

> Once the C library works independently and equivalently to the R package, we could consider moving the C functions to a separate
>   repository, that would be a dependency for the R package

Yes, this seems sensible -- have the R package retrieve the C source code as necessary when building / developing the package. This way they can be effectively decoupled.

Comment: Thanks. 1) "separate functions for reading configuration files in C" is an alternative to our current approach that uses xmlToList in R to read an input file, 2) re "main" we want to be able to compute entirely in C by passing a configuration file to the executable.